# Detecting Process Minimised State in .NET (VB/C#) on Windows 10

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, rdp

I've searched about for this for days now and can't seem to get anywhere.
A issue is occurring now that we've moved some engineers to Windows10. One of our apps allows the launching of RDP windows for selected servers. It seems that now when minimising an RDP window, no event is raised in WinForms which was causing an issue where the forms were hidden and never unhidden.

I've worked out a solution to initial problem but this has given way to a new one.

**I need to find out whether an RDP window is in Minimised state so that I can flag this on a timer tick to the app.**

I have tried using the MainWindowHandle of the selected process and attempted to Implement [IsIconic](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/ms633527), however this no longer seems to work with Windows10 processes.

Any help would be  greatly appreciated as I am pulling my hair out.

Below is the direction i'm moving in with the code, am I completely off?

```
    Private Sub CheckMinimisedTimer_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles CheckMinimisedTimer.Tick
    Dim p As Process = Process.GetProcesses().Where(Function(x) x.MainWindowTitle = $"{Me.Text} RDP CLIENT").FirstOrDefault()
    If p IsNot Nothing Then
        Dim i As Boolean = p.MainWindowHandle
        If Not i Then
            Me.WindowState = FormWindowState.Minimized
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Is this about the actual RDP window or a window of yours _inside_ an RDP screen?

Comment: I believe the app is started as a "RemoteApp", right?

Comment: So the app window seems to keep control at all times which is fine. But if you maximise the RDP window it uses it's own control bar at the top, minimising from this seems to keep it as 'maximised' but just in a hidden state and still on the task bar.


@bommelding just the RDP app at the moment, it's fine when interacting with my app, I just need to know how to detect the window state of it

Comment: @NineBerry it seems to be a standard client when launched and its process falls under the WinForms app process tree

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the solution with a lot more digging and some help from a friend, Seems like Marshaling the Bool on the IsIconic function did the trick.

```
    <DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet:=CharSet.Auto, SetLastError:=True)>
Public Shared Function IsIconic(ByVal hWnd As IntPtr) As <MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)> Boolean
End Function

Private Sub CheckMinimisedTimer_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles CheckMinimisedTimer.Tick
    Dim p As Process = Process.GetProcesses().Where(Function(x) x.MainWindowTitle = $"{Me.Text} RDP CLIENT").FirstOrDefault()
    If p IsNot Nothing Then
        Dim i As IntPtr = p.MainWindowHandle
        If IsIconic(i) Then
            Me.WindowState = FormWindowState.Minimized
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```